# Dynamic ListItem height

Tags: android, listview, listitem

How can i set the height of ListItems programmatically and/or how can i create ListItems programmatically? I'm currently using a custom ListItem.xml with a custom adapter, but the ListItems only have a fixed height. That creates lots of unused space, because the ListItems don't have the same contents.
Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: Please post some code...

Answer (score 0):

You should use an custom array adapter and depends of the content of your item you can change the height of your itemView. You can find some examples in google.

http://sogacity.com/how-to-make-a-custom-arrayadapter-for-listview/

http://devtut.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/custom-arrayadapter-for-a-listview-android/

In the arrayAdapter you could check if there is a field or not, and set this "field view" height = 0 for example, or View.INVISIBLE.

**I edit for more explicative version:**

In your adapter you have: `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)`

you can modify as your wish the `convertView` to assign more or less height. If You dont post some code I cant help more sorry.

Comment: Your samples also use a ListItem.xml, but that doesn't help me. Like i said, the contents of my ListItems are different and so I need a solution to set the height programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 int totalHeight = 0;
    int desiredWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(),    MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
        listItem.measure(desiredWidth, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() *  (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
```

And see this link this will help to you
http://kk-brothers.blogspot.in/2011/09/dynamically-change-listview-height.html